# Using react-native-router-flux with redux, how to update state in the view component?

Tags: ios, routes, react-native, redux, react-redux

## The issue:

I have tried to use redux in combination with the routing provided by [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux).

In simple words, it is not working:

- redux state modifications will not appear in view, but can be logged successfully to console
- every time an action is taken, the whole component tree with the scenes will be recreated, which results in lots of warnings in console, that a scene with the key "xyz" was already created.

## What i did:

I used the official example application of react-native-router-flux and added a simple counter-example based on redux:

- a simple state: "counter" (might be an integer)
- reducers and actions (increment, decrement)

Below i will show some code, but also one will find my [example application](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-router-flux) on github, please feel free to check it out: https://github.com/itinance/react-native-router-flux. The *"Example"* Directory is the original example application. And ***"ExampleRedux"*** is a copy of the example with a redux stack and example reducers (a counter), what i am talking about here.

**The main application** component with provider and store:

```
import * as reducers from './components/reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);

export default class Example extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ExampleContainer/>
          </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

**My reducers:**

```
const initialState = {
  count: 0
};

export default function counter(state = initialState, action = {}) {

  switch (action.type) {
      case "INCREMENT":
        console.log("do increment", state,
            {
                ...state,
                count: state.count + 1
            }
        );

      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count + 1
      };
    case "DECREMENT":
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count - 1
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**The inner application container for redux' "connect":**

I pass the state and actions to the scene component:

```
<Scene key="launch" component={Launch} title="Launch" initial={true} state={state} {...actions} />
```

The whole code of this ExampleContainer:

```
class ExampleContainer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { state, actions } = this.props;
        console.log("Props", this.props, state, actions); // everything ok here

        return <Router createReducer={reducerCreate}>
            <Scene key="modal" component={Modal} >
                <Scene key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
                    <Scene key="echo" clone component={EchoView} />
                    <Scene key="register" component={Register} title="Register"/>
                    <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="Replace" type="replace"/>
                    <Scene key="launch" component={Launch} title="Launch" initial={true} state={state} {...actions} />
                    .... lots of other scenes ...
                    </Scene>
                </Scene>
                <Scene key="error" component={Error}/>
            </Scene>
        </Router>;
    }
}


export default connect(state => ({
   state: state.counter
 }),
 (dispatch) => ({
   actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
 })
)(ExampleContainer);
```

And this is the dead easy LaunchScreen having simple counter functionality (and example routes for demonstrating the routing):

```
class Launch extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
    }

    render(){
        const { state, increment, decrement } = this.props;

        console.log("Props 2: ", this.props, state, increment, decrement);

        return (
            <View {...this.props}  style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Launch page</Text>

                <Text>{state.count}</Text>

                <Button onPress={increment}>Increment</Button>

                <Button onPress={()=>Actions.login({data:"Custom data", title:"Custom title" })}>Go to Login page</Button>
                <Button onPress={Actions.register}>Go to Register page</Button>
                <Button onPress={Actions.register2}>Go to Register page without animation</Button>
                <Button onPress={()=>Actions.error("Error message")}>Popup error</Button>
                <Button onPress={Actions.tabbar}>Go to TabBar page</Button>
               <Button onPress={Actions.pop}>back</Button>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

The actions are perfectly dispatched when clicking on Increment-Button. In the console the new state can be logged successfully. It increments one by one with every click. But not in the view.

When i ommit the router and scenes and only activate the launch screen as a single component, everything works fine.

### Question:

How to make this redux application work, that views will update their state correctly?

For the sake of completeness, the whole code can be found on [github](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-router-flux).

Comment: FYI - There is no ExampleRedux folder on the master branch of the fork you provided. Did you put it on a different branch? I'm interested in looking at the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have probably forgotten to connect the `Launch` component to the store. What you want to do is similar to what you have done in `ExampleContainer`, i.e.

```
export default connect(state => ({
   state: state.counter
 }),
 (dispatch) => ({
   actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
 })
)(Launch);
```

and then the correct values will show up in your log

Comment: Yes, you're right, thank you! This makes it work: https://github.com/itinance/react-native-router-flux/commit/65db001441406878a56b4ee8215825ae44ad4626